# tableview not being populated but array is

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using the following code to populate an array, and then have the count of that array determine the row amount.  However, the assignment statement continues to iterate for some reason, and the table view never even appears.

Code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Contacts
import ContactsUI
import Firebase
import SendBirdSDK

class Profile: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    var name = [String]()
    var phoneNo = [String] ()
    var user1cred = ""
    var user2cred = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        //put code below
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ContactCell", bundle: nil)

        self.myTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let myuser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

        let contactRef = ref.child("Users").child((myuser?.uid)!).child("Contacts")
        contactRef.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            //creates enumerator of snapshot children
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                //adds the phone numbers of users contacts to array
                self.phoneNo.append(rest.key )
                self.name.append(rest.value as! String)

            }
            print("Below is size of phoneNo")
            print(self.phoneNo.count)
            print("Below is name:")
            print(self.name)
            print("below is phone no")
            print(self.phoneNo)
        })
        //self.myTableView.reloadData() //<<<<<<<<<<<<< RELOADS TABLEVIEW

    } //end of viewDidLoad()


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("test coiunt")
        print(phoneNo.count)
        print("The number of sections is: " + String(phoneNo.count))
        return phoneNo.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ContactCell

        //below gets the index
        let val = indexPath.row

        //below assigns the values of the fields on the cell
        cell.contactName.text = (name[val])

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        //below sets the value for the cell height
        return 90.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //below prints the name of the selected user
        print(name[indexPath.row])

        //get the users to pass into below function
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let myuser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
        var contactNum = ""

        let userInfo = ref.child("Users").child((myuser?.uid)!)
        userInfo.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
           //get the current users credentials
            self.user1cred = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "/Email").value as! String
            let user1PW = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "/Password").value as! String
        })


        let user2Name = name[indexPath.row]
        let user2Info = ref.child("Users").child((myuser?.uid)!).child("Contacts")
        user2Info.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {

            print(rest.value as! String)
            print(user2Name)
            if((rest.value as! String) == user2Name) {
                //this means that it has iterated to the correct user
                self.user2cred = rest.key

            } else {
                //do NOTHING this is the wrong user being iterated on
            }
            }

        })

        /*
        //below inserts a new cell into the table view, below the selected cell
        // Update Table Data
        myTableView.beginUpdates()
        myTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
            NSIndexPath(forRow: (indexPath.row)+1, inSection: 0)
            ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DDOCell")
        myTableView.endUpdates() */

        //below reloads the table view after changes are made
        myTableView.reloadData()


        let user1 = SBDUserListQuery.init(userIds: ["2077103974"])
        let user2 = SBDUserListQuery.init(userIds: ["2077103975"])
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        print(user1)
        print(user2)
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")


        //below creates a channel between the two users
        //needs to be replaced by a query for the user
        SBDGroupChannel.createChannel(withUserIds: ["2077103974", "2077103975"], isDistinct: true, completionHandler: { (channel, error) in

            if(error != nil) {
                print("creation error!!!!")


            } else {
                //this means the channel was successfully created

                print("Channel created")


                 //below sends a test message in the channel
                 channel!.sendUserMessage("Test Message", completionHandler: { (userMessage, error) in
                 if error != nil {
                        NSLog("Error: %@", error!)
                        return
                 } else {
                        print("Test message sent")
                        //also segue to the chatting view screen
                    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChattingView") as! Profile
                    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

                 }

                 }) // end of sendUserMessage

            }

        }) //end of channelCreate

        /*
        * attach listener to text box, and show user typing(using the start typing method)
        */



        /*
        *Allow the receiving of messages
        */
    }
}
```

Below is the code that is printed out, to help with the debugging process.

```
User Logged In
test coiunt
0
The number of sections is: 0
test coiunt
0
The number of sections is: 0
test coiunt
0
The number of sections is: 0
test coiunt
0
The number of sections is: 0
Below is size of phoneNo
4
Below is name:
["Daniel Higgins", "Test2 Bot2", "John Appleseed", "John Appleseed"]
below is phone no
["5554787672", "5558881234", "8885551212", "8885555512"]
Successfully SendBird Login
```

Additionally, if it will help the current dataSource and delegate for the tableView is set to the View Controller it is embedded in

Comment: Why aren't you reloading the table view once the data is loaded?

Comment: I tried, that before.  I just commented it out when I was changing something.  Still didn't work.

Comment: See the linked answer. It needs to be in the proper place and wrapped in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: @rmaddy that doesn't solve the issue.  The code is returning 4 iterations of the value for PhoneNo.count by running the function: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` multiple times, which should only be called once.  This seems to be why it is not populating the tableview, because it doesn't think there are any cells to return.